If diodes fail open with an overcurrent condition, why do they sometimes fail shorted from reverse polarity in a power supply?
I've been doing some research on how diodes fail, and to my understanding, diodes (specifically traditional and Schottky) fail open when their rated current is exceeded for an extended period of time, and fail short when their maximum reverse voltage rating is exceeded for an extended period of time.
I also understand that power supplies often have a diode placed in reverse bias in-between the power supply voltage output and GND to protect against reverse polarity from another voltage source. If a voltage source is applied to the power supply the wrong way, then the diode will short the external voltage source, which sometimes does damage the diode, causing it to fail short. I have read of some cases where this can happen, so now I'm trying to understand this:

Do diodes usually fail open when their current rating is exceeded?
If they do, then why do diodes in power supplies sometimes fail short?

Image of Power Supply Reverse Polarity Diode



Yes an over current condition can cause a diode to fail open. This is because the current will physically heat the diode and cause it to burn, removing the conductive path.
If you reverse bias a diode, there will become a voltage at which the diode will fail as the voltage eventually causes the junction to break down. The failure is effectively a short, though it would also be possible for an overvoltage condition to produce an over current and burn the diode out as well.
As a simple method of reverse polarity protection, it is common to use a diode across the input terminals, reversed. That is to say, the anode cathode of the diode is connected to the positive power input. In the event that the power supply is reversed, the diode will conduct, limiting the voltage to its forward voltage. So if you connect a 15V power supply the wrong way round, instead of the device getting -15V in, it gets -0.7V (or whatever the forward voltage of the diode is) which is much better. This diode will effectively act as a short, so usually this is paired with some kind of current limit - either a fuse or a power supply with current limiting - to avoid either damaging the power supply or the diode.


Hi,
I guess you meant cathode in ".... the anode of the diode is connected to the positive power input terminal".

Diodes can fail open or short. If maximum current for the conditions (heat sinking, ambient temperature) is exceeded then the die can fail short, and that’s the normal mode of failure for semiconductors. It takes less current to get damaging heating in reverse bias because the voltage across the diode is much higher.
At very high currents, the connections can be vaporized, the leads melted, the package blown apart etc. just like a fuse (a poorly characterized fuse).
In the case of a diode connected across the input to protect against reversed supply, the result will depend on the diode, on whatever is in series with the diode in the circuit (maybe a fuse, maybe there is a resistor- fusible or otherwise) but also very much on the source resistance of the incorrectly connected supply. A 1N4004, 1N5404 or 1N5819 will very likely have no problem with a 12V 500mA (or even 2A) switching supply, but a car battery will blow it apart unless a fuse blows first, and it would not be surprising to find the diode failed short even if the fuse opens. A linear 3A supply would probably cause a 1N4004 to fail short unless it has fold back current limiting.
Incidentally, diodes can have substantial voltage across them in forward bias at high current, and the circuit may not actually be protected. If the diode takes a momentary fault current of 50A and ‘only’ 5A flows through the ‘protected’ circuit, the latter may be destroyed. Schottky diodes are better in this regard since the protected circuit usually has effectively normal diode junctions, but it may not be enough. For that reason, series protection such as the classic MOSFET, or a series diode or bridge rectifier of you can live with the voltage drop, may be preferred. Another method, suitable for some extremely high current situations, is to use a relay that only pulls in with the appropriate input polarity.

Schottky are tricky; they have lower voltage drop within ratings, but can have higher internal resistance, making them less suited to surge conditions. SiC schottky are an extreme example, with (8.3ms) surge rating just a few times rated current; the PN guard ring junction dominates at such currents(!).

@TimWilliams Unless there's a detailed spec as to what kind of abuse the user might subject it to, it's hard to come up with an optimized design. I recall one spec (might have been a government customer) where they deemed any inputs had to be able to withstand mains voltage without damage, fuses blowing or loss of calibration. Tricky but do-able if they are willing to pay for it.

They always fail short first.  At least, experientially.  But I can't think of any particular mechanisms that would do otherwise.
Physically speaking, the junction overheats (in part or whole), becomes intrinsic (thermal carrier concentration exceeds doping level), it's a short both ways, and fault current flows.
Some degree of this may be recoverable if the pulse is kept short, but heat also causes warpage and decomposition of the plastic packaging, fatigue of bonding / die-attach, etc.  The part is not likely to survive very long at this level, whether in terms of excess temperature (beyond Tj(max)), or number of cycles.
If current or time is not otherwise limited, melting ensues, and the part ends up a short circuit, permanently.
This can take place in some 100s µs (typical for transistors) to 10s of ms (rectifiers).
Beyond this point, it's just a lump of metal and wire, and normal fusing applies.  In particular, bond wires can melt, vaporize and fail open.  In the process, the packaging can melt and decompose, "letting out the magic smoke" -- or even be propelled as shrapnel.  After the ensuing arc flash subsides (if applicable, given sufficient current and voltage), an open circuit can result.
Whether you consider (or perceive) this to all happen at once, determines whether failure seems random, or correlated one way or another.  I posit that, when divided into this two-stage event, the correlation is 100%.
Now, you may not have evidence to prove this sequence of events in any given failure -- how often do we have an oscilloscope hooked to every component in a circuit, in the exact time frame when a fault occurs? -- so, it might still be up to chance based on available data.  But we can still draw reasonable suspicion based on circuit design, what was happening, etc.
Basically:
Assume failure means short, until it blows open as a fuse.
The short always occurs in failure, but fusing only occurs if sufficient energy is available to do so.

From another angle: I can disprove the overcurrent hypothesis directly.  Not that one counterexample is any indication of likelihood, but at least to say it's not an absolute.  And not that this is any more than hearsay in this post, but taking this at my word:
I tested several rectifiers the other day, under condition of automotive load dump.  For a 100A peak, 240ms (10%-10%) surge:

1N4148 failed short (fracture evident on glass body; leads smoked). Possible that some parts would fuse open, or break apart, given more trials.
1N4007 failed short (no magic smoke release or other outward signs of failure).
1N5408 survived (5 pulses / 1 min).
I also tested plain wire, bare: as thin as 28AWG survived this condition -- though it got incandescent in the process (but not quite to the melting point!).


You can use a P-MOSFET at the input to block reverse voltages, with a low forward-voltage drop and without concern about it going open or short, as long as its voltage rating is about the applied reverse voltage.
For a normal positive supply voltage, the P-MOSFET's source is connected to the supply, the drain to the load, and the gate to ground.
